# Given a FASTA file with a set of genes, how do I determine that set's conservation among a genetic order?

Tags: python, blast, blastp, orthofinder

Given a set of genes in a FASTA-formatted file, for example: `exFasta.fa`, what is the best way to determine how well conserved the genes in that file are among an order of organisms, for example: Orthoptera?

BLAST is an obvious option, but I am not sure that it is the most efficient way considering there are likely thousands of organisms in that order. OrthoFinder also comes across as a valid option, but I am not sure how to implement such a thing considering the required inputs.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are these annotated, known genes? Or do you also need to detect/identify the potential homologs in the target species?

Comment: Orthoptera (grasshoppers, crickets, locust) will be annotated (mostly). What they want to do is skim the draft genomes of Orthoptera. I like @gringers answer, it's a good one. As a project it would work.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible that [MOLE-BLAST](https://blast.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/moleblast/moleblast.cgi) could help for you:

> MOLE-BLAST is an experimental tool that helps taxonomists find closest database neighbors of submitted query sequences. It computes a multiple sequence alignment (MSA) between the query sequences along with their top BLAST database hits, and generates a phylogenetic tree. Query sequences in the tree are denoted with highlighted node labels. If the input sequences come from different genes or loci, MOLE-BLAST can cluster them and compute an MSA and a phylogenetic tree for each locus separately. This tool may eventually be incorporated into our supported suite of BLAST applications based on the feedback we receive.

I haven't actually used MOLE-BLAST, but I have used [Smart BLAST](https://blast.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/smartblast/), which does a somewhat similar phylogenetic search (although on a restricted diverse taxonomic set) for protein queries.

Comment: thank you! I'll try that.